# ESXi add datastore without partitioning

Tags: vmware-esxi, datastore

I've recently started playing with ESXI and now want to move all my current data (movies etc) to an openfiler vm image.

Currently I have esxi 4.1 running off a Patriot XT memory stick and a 500gb hdd for the VM datastore which I will put OF on.

How do I go about adding in the other hard drives I have to make them available to the OF machine without losing the data on them? They are currently formatted as NTFS

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add a datastore (which is used to store virtual machine images and ISOs, not data files as seen by a guest OS), you want to add the disks as Raw Device Mappings to the VM in question. In the VM hardware settings, click Add, Hard Disk, then choose Raw Device Mapping rather than a new or existing virtual disk.

Comment: The Raw Device Mappings is disabled how do i Enable it?